# XML3D: Exporting animations from blender

Tags: javascript, blender, xml3d

How one should prepare the animations for export to xml3d?
Does the exporter supports pose library?
Or the exported animations are keyframe based. Is there any documentation where I can check how exporter maps the animation data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to this exporter:
https://github.com/ksons/xml3d-blender-exporter/

This exporter supports armatures in many but probably not all ways supported by Blender. Here is a very coarse mapping from blender objects to XML3D elements:
https://github.com/ksons/xml3d-blender-exporter/wiki/Mappings

Comment: Does it export poses or keyframes or just the bones?

Comment: It exports bones and keyframe animations.

Comment: Do you plan to export poses from blender pose library too? What about non-linear animations?